# Filter alternative in Snowflake with aggregations

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

Tell me if I am wrong

Replacing the below postgres SQL query :

```
sum(col_1) filter(where fin_col = 'Base') / 10^5 as spend
```

with below Snowflake query :

```
  sum(case when fin_col = 'Base' then col_1/pow(10,5) end) as spend
```

I want to make sure that above queries will give the same results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: better `sum(case when fin_col = 'Base' then col_1 end)/pow(10,5) as spend` in order to perform the same float operations, many additions and one division.

Comment: Thanks alot for clarifying @Stefanov.sm

Answer (score 4):

The pattern `sum(col_1) filter(where fin_col = 'Base') / 10^5 as spend` is called conditional aggregation.

As for today, Snowflake does not support `FILTER` clause. If it was a

```
COUNT(*) FILTER(where fin_col='Base')
```

then  it has a [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html) function as direct replacement.

```
COUNT_IF(fin_col='Base')
```

There is no **SUM_IF** function so the pattern is to use `CASE` expression inside and the fact that aggregate functions skip NULL:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN fin_col = 'Base' THEN col_1 ELSE NULL END)/pow(10,5) AS spend
```

`ELSE NULL` is default for CASE and could be skipped

```
SUM(CASE WHEN fin_col = 'Base' THEN col_1 END)/pow(10,5) AS spend
```

Or:

```
SUM(IFF(fin_col='Base', col_1, NULL))/pow(10,5) AS spend
```

Answer (score 1):

The first reply is correct. However you should be intentional about the `else` case as Snowflake `sum()` can output `null` if either:

- every value is null
- no records are covered

This differs from `count()` which will never output `null` (even in these cases, it will output 0). Using `else 0` is generally a better formula for `sum()`, but it depends on your situation!